# how to add 1 user in multiple groups in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007, csom

I want to add 1 user in multiple groups in sharepoint 2013.
This code for adding 1 user at 1 group is working for me.

```
 Dim clientContext As New ClientContext("http://Server/DomainName/")
        ' Get the SharePoint web  
        Dim web As Web = clientContext.Web
        Dim user As User = web.EnsureUser("FirstName LastName")
        ' Get the specific site group by name  
        Dim group As Group = web.SiteGroups.GetByName("Managment")
        ' Add a user to the specific group  
        group.Users.AddUser(user)
        ' Execute the query to the server  
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Now I want to add user  in bulk groups.

How can i call a array here.

```
' Get the specific site group by name  
            Dim group As Group = web.SiteGroups.GetByName("Managment")
```

I am getting the array which has all the group names.Now how to add Groups in an array as collection type.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same code and create a loop?

Or use [SPDash](http://www.spdash.com)